# Azure IoT Hub blocked for two consecutive days, will not let me change to a paid tier

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I have a free tier subscription to Azure IoT hub with only two edge devices connected to it, one of them mostly off. Yesterday, it looks like my hub recorded a slew of messages--within 45 minutes (5 to 5:45 pm PST), 25K messages were recorded by the hub. A few related issues.

1. I'm not sure what these messages were. I'll add message storage for the future, but wondering if there's a way to debug this.
2. Ever since then, I haven't been able to use the IoT hub. I get a "message count exceeded" error. That made sense till around 5 pm PST today (same day UTC), but not sure why it is still blockign me after that.
3. I tried to change my F1 to a basic tier to basic, but that wasn't allowed because I am apparently "not allowed to downgrade"

Any help with any of these?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.*I'm not sure what these messages were. I'll add message storage for the future, but wondering if there's a way to debug this.*

[IoT Hub operations monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-operations-monitoring) enables you to monitor the status of operations on your IoT hub in real time. You can use it to monitor Device identity operations,Device telemetry,Cloud-to-device messages,Connections,File uploads and Message routing.

> 2.*Ever since then, I haven't been able to use the IoT hub. I get a "message count exceeded" error. That made sense till around 5 pm PST
>   today (same day UTC), but not sure why it is still blockign me after
>   that.*

IoT Hub Free edition enables you to transmit up to a total of 8,000 messages per day, and register up to 500 device identities. The device identity limit is only present for the Free Edition.

> 3.*I tried to change my F1 to a basic tier to basic, but that wasn't allowed because I am apparently "not allowed to downgrade".*

You cannot switch from Free to one of the paid editions. The free edition is meant to test out proof-of-concept solutions only.

Comment: This does not quite answer the second issue. I have the same problem. Yesterday I exceeded my Free Tier quota with 9500/8000. Today (a new UTC day) the quota is not reset, still "exceeded". [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling) does not say a word about resetting the limits. When should it be reset?

Answer (score 0):

Confirming the earlier answer, the only solution is to delete the old hub and create a new free one, which is simple enough.

I still haven't figured out what those specific error messages were, but I do notice that when there are errors such as CA certificate auth failures, lots of messages get sent up. I'm still working with MSFT support on the CA certificate signing issues, but this one is a side effect.

For future reference, look at yoru hub's metrics, and note that (i) quote gets reset midnight UTC, but (ii) net violations do not.